# How can i swap the height and width of a rectangle without changing the south western point?

Tags: java

I need to  switch the height and width without changing the _pointSW value.

These are the variables:

```
private int _width; 
private int _height;
private Point _pointSW;
```

I am not able to find the changeSides function on the oracle website which is the function they say to use in my assigment so i am not sure if there is some sort of command to do this? any assistance would be great thanks

```
public void changeSides()
    {
                      
    }
```

Comment: Which java version are you using? Note that the API changes with every release. As far as I am aware, there is no `changeSides` method.

Comment: You really need to explain clearly what changeSides() is supposed to do.

Comment: I think that `changeSides` is either a method you are expected to write, or one provided by your instructor.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong : a rectangle is defined by one point and its height and width ?
so basically if you swap the two values it is not the same rectangle anymore ? 
In this case just do : 
width += height;
height = width - height
width -= height
this should work

Comment: Where are the indicated variables defined?  Re-read the assignment - perhaps you are supposed to implement the `changeSides` method.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions**

- To increase the height, means stretching the *medium* upwards.
- To increase the width, means stretching the *medium* rightwards.

---

**Notes**

*let* pos *be the southeast point*
*let* width *, and* height *be the two sizes we start width*
*let* corner *be the southwest point*

**Pseudo code**

```
// swapping the width and height can
// be thought of as subtracting away width
// then adding the height value.
corner.x = pos.x + height - width
```

---

If any assumptions are incorrect, invalid, or needs changing. Feel free to notify me!

Answer (score 0):

you need a temporary variable for this one.

```
    public void changeSides() {

    int temp = width;
    int width = height;
    int height = temp;

    }
```